# When I am running my program it immediately crashes the IDE

Tags: c++

The error message says:

```
/tmp/something-148ec2.o: In function `main':
something.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/main-c94e00.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
compiler exit stat
```

And here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int marks[] = { 25, 90, 98, 82, 60 };
        int i = 0;
    // while loop
    while (true) {
        cout<<marks[i]<<endl;
                i++;
        if (i == 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet compiles and works fine. https://godbolt.org/z/f3TMMr So a [mre] is needed.

Comment: Does `something.cpp` happen to `#include "main.cpp"`?

Comment: Your program does not "crash the IDE", you get a linker error, because apparently you have two definitions of the `main()` function, or you have the one source file in your project twice.

Comment: It's a linker problem. You might be inadvertently linking an executable to the objects created with the source files. CMake can do these kinds of things if the name of your executable, `mycode`,  is the same and if it is in the same directory as the source file `mycode.cpp`. To see if that's the problem, delete the executable and try to recompile. Then correct the CMakeLists.txt file. Or better - build the executable in a directory other than the one with the sources.

Comment: What you show is not a [mre]. The second file ("named main.cpp") which is built along with the shown file is missing. And that is also the answer.

Comment: You probably have 2 files in the same project both of which have a main function. For Visual Studio, right click on the unneeded file, select properties and then select exclude from build

Comment: That's not the complete code - according to the error message, you also have a file called "something.cpp".

Answer (score -2):

I think you are using CMake.
If so then you can have only one file containing the `main` function.
In order to use multiple files with main function you have to register the C++ executable in your CMake file.

Most IDEs like Netbeans, CLion, Eclipse (I think) have the same kind of behavior.

I use CLion and this problem can be resolved by installing [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8352-c-c--single-file-execution/)

This extension registers your C++ file in CMake File.

Comment: Can you try to write "normal" english. Most of us are non native speakers and the "u r" is meaningless for me! What you want to tell us? BTW: That is not an answer, maybe a a command...

Comment: StackOverflow does not require perfect English, or I myself would be pretty lost. But you cannot seriously believe that "u r" using a polite and matter-of-fact way of writing with phrasings like this. Please demonstrate that you respect this community and spend a minimum of effort on approrpriate wording. Other things you are probbaly capable of with some care are puncuation and capitalisation at the start of new sentences. I won't mention grammar, because that is where I can hardly improve your post. Cheers. Have fun.

Comment: @Eddymage I appreciate your effort. But in this case I would like to help the author themself to come to grips with appropriate phrasing. I guess your edit will be approved by others, but please keep this in mind for the future. Have fun.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I suggested the edit before the comments showed up: indeed, I completely agree with them. I should have think the same.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions/corrections i will be careful next time,